# Hot to use method reference operator with nested methods?

Tags: java, method-reference

Hi I want to know how to use method reference operator for nested methods.
I need this to maintain consistent style in code.

I want to convert something like this

```java
    .filter(a -> a.getB().getC().getD().isE())
```

to something like this

```java
    .filter(A::getB::getC::getD::isE)
```

even something like this would be fine

```java
    .filter(_.getB().getC().getD().isE())
```

I want to remove this

```java
    a -> a
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do any of this in Java. Nested method reference syntax is not supported while `_` is available in other JVM based languages e.g. Groovy has `it`.

You are stuck with some variant of `a -> a` unless you can rewrite the stream pipeline to:

```
.map(A::getB)
.map(B::getC)
.map(C::getD)
.filter(D::isE)
```

however with above you have a stream of `D` and not `A`.

You could also modify class `A` by adding a new method

```
public boolean hasE() {
  return getB().getC().getD().isE();
}
```

which lets you do `filter(A::hasE)`.

Comment: The problem is when I implement as you suggested I'll get output Type D, but in reality I would need type A.  The _ wildcard is lifted from scala.

Comment: @sampathsukesh I know, it's just that what you want is not possible with current Java syntax. I'd love someone to explain this to me.

Comment: Can I do something in Z ( assuming it is the calling function )

```java
public static bool foo(A a) {
    return a.getB().getC().getD().isE();
}

.filter(Z::foo)
```

Comment: @sampathsukesh you can do this, but this makes code potentially less readable, instead of one `filter()` someone now has to go to type `Z` and understand `foo`. If `foo` is not reused frequently it's a bit pointless.

Comment: I think I can agree on that. I wanted to know if this is possible. I am converting Scala code to pure Java where I've encountered this problem where ( _.getB().getC().....) exists.

Answer (score 1):

You could also make a static method that takes A, so you don't need to modify the A class as suggested by Karol.

```
static boolean isE(A a) {
   return a.getB().getC().getD().isE();
}
```

Then your filter would look like:

```
.filter(MyType::isE)
```

(assuming MyType is the class where you have added the static method)